# Get output from a shell script that does ssh two level

Tags: bash, docker, shell, ssh

I have two shell scripts like below:

Script1:

```
ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null my_username@jump_box <<EOF
ls
ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null actual_host <<EOF1
sudo docker ps --format='{{json .}}'
EOF1
EOF
```

Script2:

```
details=nothing
ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null my_username@jump_box <<EOF
ls
details=$(ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null actual_host "sudo docker ps --format='{{json .}}'")
EOF
echo "${details}"
```

I need the docker details in a varilable in my local machine so that I can do some operations on it. The first script runs fine and I can see the output of the docker command on my local machine but the second script doesn't work. It seems to be hung/stuck and doesn't do anything and I have to forcefully quit it.

Comment: Script2 doesn't work because the `$( )` expression gets run on the local computer (and it sets `details` on the jump box instead of the local computer). Do you actually need to run `ls` on the jump box? Would using [`ssh -J my_username@jump_box ...`](https://superuser.com/questions/1488097/does-openssh-support-multihop-login/1488100) simplify this?

Comment: @GordonDavisson No, the 'ls' was just for some testing purposes. I dont need it. Will try the multihop option, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comment from @[Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson), use a jumpbox.

But you can define it in the `~/.ssh/config` file, too.

```
HOST my_jump_box
  hostname jump_box
  user my_username
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null 

HOST actual
  hostname actual_hostname
  user actual_user
  ProxyJump my_jump_box
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null 
  RemoteCommand sudo docker ps --format='{{json .}}'"
```

Then you can just use `ssh actual`

To fetch the output `details=$(ssh actual)`.

Btw. Your specific problem could also be solved by changing script2 to:

```
#!/bin/bash
details=$(./script1)
echo "$details"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The latter approach worked fine. Will try the former approach as well. It would have been so good if this could have been done using just one script rather than two and calling one from another.

Comment: @TAnna You can do it in just one script, but you have to enclose the entire `ssh` command *and the here-document* inside `$( )` (and the close parenthesis has to be on the line after the `EOF` marker).